# Deserialize object with passed file type determined at runtime

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, casting

I currently have a serializable object that I am storing in the database as XML. It's a simple little class that contains a few variables. It would look something like this:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class ExampleClassToSerialize
    {
        public bool ImABool;
        public int ImAnInt;
        public string ImAString;
    }
```

It worked fine back when I specified statically what type the object was (ExampleClassToSerialize type). But I later added another serializable class and wanted to make the method more generic... and have had a horrible time with it! I tried just passing in an object and doing "typeof" but that didn't work out, so then I tried passing in the type as a Type object... also no go. This is what I have so far:

```
   //Returns a generic item from the Table
    private bool GetXMLControlTextFromDB(string objectToGet, object objectToFill, Type type)
    {
        try
        {
            // Grab object from stored procedure
            using (SqlConnection conn = My_Connection)
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[spGetStuffFromTable]", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TehObjectorz", objectToGet));

                conn.Open();
                string serializedObject = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                conn.Close();

                //Deserialize the object pulled from DB
                try
                {
                    if (serializedObject != "")
                    {
                        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
                        using (var reader = new StringReader(serializedObject))
                        {
                            objectToFill = Convert.ChangeType(serializer.Deserialize(reader), type);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                        return false;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   //Do Stuff with exception
           Return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
    //Do more stuff with exception
    Return false;
        }
    }
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Source: System.Xml
Message: There is an error in XML document (1, 1).
```

Can anyone think of a better way to do this?

Thank you!

UPDATE:

```
-InnerException 
{"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."}  
  System.Exception {System.Xml.XmlException}

StackTrace "at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)\r\n   
            at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)\r\n   
            at Namespace.GetXMLObjectFromDB(String objectToGet, Object objectToFill, Type type) in *stuff*\ProjectFile.cs 2081" 
            string
```

NOTE:

The problem is that it worked fine before I changed the type. When I did

```
 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(ExampleClassToSerialize.GetType());
```

and

```
 objectToFill = (ExampleClassToSerialize)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

it worked just fine :( It was only when I tried to do this runtime determined convert that it started failing.

Comment: My guess is the XML is not well-formed.  Check the `InnerException`.

Comment: New Notes on the question!